# Problem with returning a variable into a function

Tags: c

I am trying to make a menu where you can add employee info and print it out. However I run into an issue where I am unable to carry down the AddEmployeeNumber down to the print function so I can define the size of the array. Anything would be appreciated! I am unsure if I did the parameters correctly too.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Employee
{
 char name[5][10];
 float hourswork[10];
 float hourspay[10];
}EmployeeNumber;


float AddEmployee()
{
 int AddEmployeeNumber;
 printf("How Many Employees Do You Want To Add: ");
 scanf("%d", &AddEmployeeNumber);

 struct Employee EmployeeNumber[AddEmployeeNumber];

 for (int i = 0; i < AddEmployeeNumber; i++)
 {
    char name[5][10];
    printf("Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &EmployeeNumber[i].name[5][10]);

    float hourswork;
    printf("Hours Worked: \n");
    scanf("%f", &EmployeeNumber[i].hourswork[10]);

    float hourspay;
    printf("Hourly Rate:\n");
    scanf("%f", &EmployeeNumber[i].hourspay[10]);

  }
   return AddEmployeeNumber;

 }



 float PrintingAllEmployees(struct Employee EmployeeNumber[])
 {
  float AddEmployee();
  struct Employee EmployeeNumber[AddEmployeeNumber];
  for (int i = 0; i < AddEmployeeNumber; i++)
 {
    printf("Name: %s", EmployeeNumber[i].name[10]);
    printf("Hours Worked: %f", EmployeeNumber[i].hourswork[10]);
    printf("Hourly Rate: %f", EmployeeNumber[i].hourspay[10]);
 }
}

float PrintingAllEmployees(struct Employee EmployeeNumber[]);

int main()
{
 int choice;
 int x = 1;
 while (x = 1)
{
 printf("Main Menu\n");
 printf("1: Add Employee\n");
 printf("2: Edit Employee\n");
 printf("3: Print A Employee\n");
 printf("4: Print All Employees\n");
 printf("5: Quit\n");
 printf("Enter Which Section You Want To Access: \n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

switch (choice)
 {
 case 1:
    AddEmployee();
    break;
 case 2:
    
    break;

 case 3:
    
    break;

 case 4:
    PrintingAllEmployees(struct Employee EmployeeNumber[]);
    break;

 case 5:
    return 0;

 default:
    printf("Sorry, Not Valid");
    break;
   }
 
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `AddEmployee` return type `float` but `AddEmployeeNumber` is of type `int` ? But it seems like you are returning it already, so save it in your main function then pass it to your print function?

Comment: Or you can save the actual count of the employees in some kind of context structure.

Comment: Tip: Use an *array of structs* and not a *struct full of arrays*. What you have here is a complete mess to use, and further, is full of ridiculously tiny character buffers. You can't even put in your own name without an overflow!

Comment: And why is `char name[5][10];` 5 arrays of 10? Also those scanf statements look incorreect.

Comment: `EmployeeNumber[i].hourswork[10]` doesn't exist. You're writing to garbage memory.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &EmployeeNumber[i].name[5][10]);` is quite wrong. That is the array definition, not the actual array element you want to use, and as such it is accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: @tadman Actually that's for Microsoft's compiler to allow the use of things like scanf, fopen, rather than scanf_s and fopen_s, there's many more but it's a valid preprocessor if you don't want to deal with _s prefix microsoft' functions.

Comment: @Irelia Ah, fair enough. There's still an alarming number of other issues here.

Comment: `while (x = 1)` doesn't do what you think it does. When doing C, develop your eye for `=` vs `==` as it is **extremely important**.

Comment: @tadman how would I fix the EmployeeNumber[i].hourswork[10] issue

Comment: A) Get rid of the useless arrays, just use a regular `float` unless each employee has multiple hours. B) Simplify, simplify, simplify your code to stay focused. `EmployeeNumber` is verbose and wrong. `Employee` is better. When you define aliases *use them* or don't bother defining.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the help, it made my code better!

Comment: Having mixed-case variable names is also very confusing. `int num` is better than `int AddEmployeeNumber`. If `num` isn't self-explanatory within the context it's used, you probably have a very confused context that needs to be simplified.

Comment: You're also declaring a ton of variables you're not using, perhaps inadvertently, as you shadow your own variables here, load data into a local structure, then **throw it out** without realizing. Tip: **Avoid global variables**. Your goal as a programmer should be to minimize, if not eliminate global state. The less you have, the better your life is.

Comment: One thing I'd recommend before you get too deep into the weeds like you have here is to find a C unit testing system you can get along with, and write unit tests for each function you're working on to verify it works as expected before combining it with others. Ensuring that each piece is correct is an *extremely powerful* time-saving tool, as well as a way to make changes with confidence, knowing your tests will break if you botched something.